# Recurring prompt to confirm Style Sheet when opening Safari - How can I get rid of it?

Tags: safari

Every time I open Safari, I'm asked to choose a style sheet.  I haven't ever chosen one.
I've tried to find one it suggests (webguard.css from an old application long removed) but it doesn't exist on my system.

I've done the Safari/Preferences/Advanced/Style sheet setting with none selected but it doesn't work.  It reverts every time to the same old question.

If I cancel, it works fine until the next time I start Safari.

I've referred this to Apple who have been through the whole diagnostics process and can't find anything.

Ultimately, it's not a show stopper, but where can I find the place to remove any reference to a style sheet in Safari?

Comment: I've written it as an actual answer so that you can mark this question as resolved - glad it worked

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be selecting a css file that does exist. Any plain text file with a .css extension should be fine. This might fix whatever setting is corrupted.

Comment: This was really helpful and resolved a long standing irritant. Many thanks.